# How come it shows up "This account is already registered" when I try to get into a MCPE server?

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I try to sign up for a server, I get a message saying that it's already been registered.

Comment: Have you signed up for that server beforehand by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your name in the settings. If it is still steve then you have to change it, try something like your last name backwards.